# In an extension, how can I define a computed property with placeholder types?

Tags: swift

I have the following code in my project:

```
extension Array {
    func unzip<A, B>() -> ([A], [B]) where Element == (A, B) {
        reduce(into: ([], [])) {
            $0.0.append($1.0)
            $0.1.append($1.1)
        }
    }
}
```

This compiles and works exactly as I'd like it to - any instance of an array of tuples can be "unzipped" into two arrays of types that match the first and second elements of the tuple.

But for style reasons I would prefer for this to be a computed property instead of a function, so it would be executed as `tupleArray.unzipped` instead of `tupleArray.unzip()`.  How do I do that?

Comment: [This is not currently possible and has been proposed.](https://forums.swift.org/t/parameterized-extensions/25563)

Comment: Not related to your question but you can simply return `(map(\.0), map(\.1))`

Comment: Btw you should extend `Sequence` instead of `Array` to support zipped types `Zip2Sequence` as well `extension Sequence {`
    `func unzip<T, U>() -> ([T], [U]) where Element == (T, U) { (map(\.0), map(\.1)) }`
`}`

Comment: You can create a computed property for Zip2Sequence types `extension Zip2Sequence {`
    `var unzip: ([Sequence1.Element], [Sequence2.Element]) { (map(\.0), map(\.1)) }`
`}`